# Get Process Location Path using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, path, location

I am trying to get the location of currently running process on your computer using PowerShell.

**Example**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox
C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
```

When I run the command

```
$path = Get-Process | Select-Object Path
Split-Path $path
```

I get the following output, which I not what I want. Why does it add **@{Path=**?

```
@{Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox
@{Path=C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
@{Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer
```

When I run `Split-Path` as follows, it gives me the correct output `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`.

```
$pshpath = "C:\Windows\sysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
Split-Path $pshpath
```

Comment: If PID is needed too, use `Get-Process -name java |  % { $_.Path + " " + $_.Id}`

Answer (score 15):

```
$path = Get-Process | Select-Object Path
```

returns an array of objects. Each object in the array will have the property 'Path' along with an optional value.

The 'path' parameter of split-path takes 'string' arguments so when you run
`Split-Path $path`

i guess each object is being converted to type string so you get the hashtable format output.

split-path can accept path values from pipeline by property name so you can do:

```
 $path | Split-path
```

if you just want the path perhaps you could try:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Path
```

Comment: For me, this just shows weird paths that are just C... :|

Answer (score 8):

To get a list of all paths just use:

```
ps | % {$_.Path}
```

or full syntax:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object {$_.Path}
```

when using:

```
$path = Get-Process | Select-Object Path
```

lets look at what $path is:

```
$path | Get-Member
```

and you get:

```
   TypeName: Selected.System.Diagnostics.Process

Name        MemberType   Definition
----        ----------   ----------
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method       type GetType()
ToString    Method       string ToString()
Path        NoteProperty System.String Path=C:\windows\system32\atieclxx.exe
```

so Path is not a **String** but a **NoteProperty**, I guess that's why you can't use `Split-Path` directly.

Comment: For those using the first syntax, it can even be cut down to `ps | % Path` as the pipeline variable and braces aren't required here.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of getting the path is by doing something like this:

```
(Get-Process -Name firefox).path
```

But, since one process can appear multiple times (I'm looking at you, `chrome.exe`), you'd get the same path repeated as many times as the process appears in the process list. IMO, a better way of getting the path is by process id (1234 as an example):

```
(Get-Process -Id 1234).path
```

Or, if you're not sure what your process' id is, you could loop through all the running processes, and then check each of them individually, piping the results to a file, for later analysis. For example:

```
$processList = Get-Process #let's get all the processes at once
$newline = "`r`n"
$tabChar = "`t"
$separator = "--------"
$file = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\proc-loc.txt" # where do we want to pipe out the output

Write-Output "Processes $newLine $separator" > $file # out with the previous contents of the file, let's start anew 

# let's loop through the list, and pick out the stuff we need
foreach($item in $processList) {
    $itemObject =  $item | Select-Object

    $itemName = $itemObject.Name
    $itemId = $itemObject.Id
    $itemPath = (Get-Process -Id $itemId).path

    Write-Output "$itemId $tabChar $itemName $tabChar $itemPath"  >> $file
}
```

If you're interested in getting the running services as well, you could expand on the previous bit, with this:

```
$serviceList = Get-WmiObject win32_service | Where {$_.state -eq "Running"}
Write-Output "$newline $newline Services $newline $separator" >> $file

foreach($item in $serviceList) {
    $itemName = $item.Name
    $itemId = $item.ProcessId
    $itemPath = $item.PathName

    Write-Output "$itemId $tabChar $itemName $tabChar $itemPath" >> $file
}
```

One thing to note, though - this won't give you a path for each and every process currently running on your system. For example, `SgrmBroker, smss, System` and some instances of `svchost` won't have a path attached to them in your output file.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove that split-path command and give a object parameter as stated below.

```
$path = Get-Process | Select-Object Path
$path.path
```

And output would be as stated below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\SelfServicePlugin.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\SettingSyncHost.exe
C:\Windows\SystemApps\ShellExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\sihost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe
```